# Need help- Query to insert an image into a table in sql developer3.0

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am using sql developer 3.0.

I need to store images as a BLOB in a table.

I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Account_images(img_id NUMBER, MP_ID NUMBER, icon BLOB);
```

The images i need to store are in

```
'C:\Project\images\'
```

Anyone please help me inserting the images into the Database wuth the sql query ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Databases are not the best storage for binary files. File system is already optimized for that task. Database should store physical address on the file system pointing to actual files.

Comment: is it one-time-job you need to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store your image in a file.

   File image=new file("'C:\Project\images\image.jpg");
2. Sql Query to insert.

   String Sql="insert into Account_images(img_id,img_id,icon) values(1,1,?)";
3. Perpare Statement

   PreparedStatement pStatement=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
4. Write file to a FileInputStream

   FileInputStream   fis =fis = new FileInputStream(image);
5. Attach fis to preparedStatement as

   pStatement.setBinaryStream(1, fis,fis.length());
6. Execute Statement

   ResultSet result=pStatement.executeUpdate();

As a whole

```
File image=new file("'C:\Project\images\image.jpg");
String Sql="insert into Account_images(img_id,img_id,icon) values(1,1,?)";
PreparedStatement pStatement=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
FileInputStream   fis =fis = new FileInputStream(image);
pStatement.setBinaryStream(1, fis,fis.length());
ResultSet result=pStatement.executeUpdate();
```